# How can I avoid only one cell that contains a table to hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, hover

I have a table inside of a cell in another table. The containing table hovers, but I want to avoid that the cell containing the table with id "table_I_don_not_want_to_hover", hovers as the other cells (td) or per line (tr). I want it maintain their colors. The problem is that I cannot change the css that makes all the table hover and it is in another file in which I don't have access, then I need to re-write the non hover behavior. This is the table:

```
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px">
                            <tbody>

                                <tr><td colspan="100" style="Text-Align:Center;Font-Size:16Px;Font-Weight:Bold">Appeso</td></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th nowrap="" class="hc" style="width: 50px">
                                        ........
                                    </th> 
                                    <th nowrap="" class="cl3">row 1</th>
                                    <th nowrap="" class="cl3">row 2</th>
                                    <th nowrap="" class="cl3">row 3</th>
                                    <th nowrap="" class="cl3">row 4</th>
                                    <th nowrap="" class="cl3">row 5</th>

                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                            <tbody class="class1">

                                    <tr class="">
                                        <td nowrap="" class="cl2" rowspan="8">
                                            <input type="checkbox" value="1111"  name="chk_p">
                                        </td> 

                                        <td nowrap=""  rowspan="8">

                                        <td nowrap="" class="c">row 1</td>
                                        <td nowrap="" class="c ">row 2</td>

                                        <td nowrap="" class="c">row3</td>
                                        <td nowrap="" class="c">row4</td>
                                        <td nowrap="" class="c">row5</td>

                                    <tr id="id" hidden="" style="display: table-row;">
                                        <td class="cl no_hover"></td>
                                        <td colspan="8" class="cl no_hover">
                                            <table id="table_I_don_not_want_to_hover" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%%">
                                                <tbody><tr class="no_hover">
                                                    <td class="dc_header_taglia">row</td>
                                                    <td class="dc_header_taglia">row</td>
                                                    <td class="dc_header_taglia">row</td>
                                                    <td class="dc_header_taglia">row</td>
                                                    <td class="dc_header_taglia">row</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                    .............
```

I have tried:

```
.no_hover{
           pointer-events: none;
         }
```

but the problem is that it avoids all the events and I have a jquery code that allows that row to appear and disappear. If I use that solution, it disables the function that make it appear/disappear.

I tried:

```
            .tr:hover > div {
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
            .tr:hover > div:hover {
              opacity: 1.0;
            }
            .td:hover > div {
                opacity: 0.5;
            }
            .td:hover > div:hover {
              opacity: 1.0;
            }
```

I am not practical with css.

Comment: Answered You Question, Simple use `not()` for this case

Comment: What does "The containing table hovers" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not()` in hover property, as bellow I implement hover property to all `td` but not to `td` having `not_hover` class,This will help you.

```css
table,tr,td
{
  border:1px solid black;
}
td:not(.not_hover):hover{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email<th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="not_hover">Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you missed this part of the original message: "I cannot change the css that makes all the table hover and it is in another file in which I don't have access"

Comment: So can you add `css` instead of changing `css`